# How can i add more than one and dynamic classes in CSS modules react

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I am using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

```js
import style from "./styles/question.module.css";

// status[0] could be 0,1,2,3,4
<p className={style[`difficulty_${status[0]}`]}>{difficulty}</p>,
```

The above code is working, but the below code is not working.

```js
// tried to add more class
<p className={`${style.difficulty} ${style[`difficulty_${status[0]}`]}}`}>{difficulty}</p>
```

Only `difficulty` class is being applied.

Comment: Try **[class1,class2].join(“ “)** it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that via using more than option:

- I prefer to use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) lib to handling classes conditions in nice way, just you need to import library and start use it..for example
  [image]
- You can use join to build all needed class
- You can build all needed class out side the className and pass it to className which its make it easy to check where is the mistake and you can control the values in easy way too..